# validation with javascript from my select using api data

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I use an API to get access to the city's subways stations using a select.

I can display information about one station, the first one (Balard). I want to display the informations of the other stations that i choose with my select after click on the submit button. But i don't know how to make it works. Can you help me please?

Here is my code:

```js
var link = 'https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/';
var apiStations = "https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/stations/metros/8";

  fetch(apiStations, {
    method: "get"
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let allstations = data.result.stations;
    let html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allstations.length; i++) {
      html += "<option value=" + allstations[i].slug + ">" + allstations[i].name + "</option>"
    }
    document.getElementById("stationmetro").innerHTML = html;
    
    function Validate() {
    var e = document.getElementById("stationmetro");
    var metroselect = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var url = this.link + 'schedules/metros/8/' + metroselect +'/A+R';
      //alert(url);
        fetch(url, {
          method: "get"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          let test= data.result.schedules;
          let dest=''
          
          for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            dest += "<div id='dataapi' value=> Direction: " + test[i].destination + " <br>Information :" +test[i].message +"<br></div>" 
          }
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = dest;
          var element = document.getElementById("dataapi");
          element.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
      })
    } Validate();
  })
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

section.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

section.container .item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>testapp</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="item" id="select">
      <p>Liste dynamique des stations de la ligne 8</p>
      <select id="stationmetro"></select>
      <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Afficher les informations" onclick="return Validate()" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="results">
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: save that data in an array and based on select item. get the item from api response array and inject that as html or text ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to it. It's data from an api so it's text and i want it to be in a div. I already did it for the the first one but now i don't know how to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some syntax issue in your code.
Please update the submit button with below syntax

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Afficher les informations" onclick="Validate()" />
```

And modify the script past with the script provided and try.

```js
var link = 'https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/';
var apiStations = "https://api-ratp.pierre-grimaud.fr/v4/stations/metros/8";

  fetch(apiStations, {
    method: "get"
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    let allstations = data.result.stations;
    let html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < allstations.length; i++) {
      html += "<option value=" + allstations[i].slug + ">" + allstations[i].name + "</option>"
    }
    document.getElementById("stationmetro").innerHTML = html;
    Validate();
    
  })
  function Validate() {
       document.getElementById("results").innerHTML =""
    var e = document.getElementById("stationmetro");
    var metroselect = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var url = this.link + 'schedules/metros/8/' + metroselect +'/A+R';
      //alert(url);
        fetch(url, {
          method: "get"
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          let test= data.result.schedules;
          let dest=''
          
          for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            dest += "<div id='dataapi' value=> Direction: " + test[i].destination + " <br>Information :" +test[i].message +"<br></div>" 
          }
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = dest;
          var element = document.getElementById("dataapi");
          element.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
      })
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It's working. Can you explain me what i did wrong? And maybe you know how i can put all my div with the data (as i tried after the foor loop)

Comment: As you can see your onclick method syntax was wrong in html.
And in script part you have kept the validation method inside your URL call so the html was not able to find the validation method.
Tip:
Whenever you are using html try using your browser console to check if their are any errors or not

Comment: Oh thank you. Do you know i can make all my div green with the result. I tried but there is only one

Comment: dest += "<div id='dataapi' style='background-color:#00FF00' value=> Direction: " + test[i].destination + " <br>Information :" +test[i].message +"<br></div>"

Just add "style='background-color:#00FF00' " like i have done above

Comment: That's a great idea